# What is this Titus metal part called?

Tags: tools, metal, connectors, adapter

I found this metal piece with the brand name Titus. What is it called and what is it for?

[image: 1]

Comment: Where'd you find it?

Comment: I found it in a cupboard under a kitchen sink, but it may not necessarily be related to plumbing.

Comment: Google did find a Titus company that makes cabinet hardware.

Comment: Has it fallen off one of the hinges? Like a slow-close mechanism?

Comment: Look at other kitchen cabinet hardware in your kitchern for a similar item.

Comment: What is the width of the center slot? Could it be for holding a dust pan or a hand broom if not a hinge piece

Comment: It is a soft close mechanism for a hinge. Google "titus soft close" and check the images tab. Chances are you'll find another one nearby to show you how it is attached.